# Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/LabWebServletHibernate]]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, servlets

I'm getting this error when running app on tomcat-8 with eclipse neon-1,it is using spring-4.3.3, hibernate-5.2.4 and maven.

```
嚴重: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/LabWebServletHibernate]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:915)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/LabWebServletHibernate]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@2b8b2271]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4969)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5099)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@93d5fda]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:706)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:111)
    ... 13 more

十一月 18, 2016 5:19:25 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
嚴重: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:915)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:787)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:923)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 6 more

十一月 18, 2016 5:19:25 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
嚴重: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:787)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:923)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 11 more

嚴重: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:316)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:492)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:821)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:589)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)

十一月 18, 2016 5:19:25 下午 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
資訊: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
十一月 18, 2016 5:19:25 下午 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
嚴重: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:316)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:492)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:821)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:589)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)

十一月 18, 2016 5:19:25 下午 org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl cleanUp
警告: Failed to retrieve JNDI naming context for container [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/LabWebServletHibernate]] so no cleanup was performed for that container
javax.naming.NamingException: No naming context bound to this class loader
    at org.apache.naming.ContextBindings.getClassLoader(ContextBindings.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl.cleanUp(NamingResourcesImpl.java:992)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl.stopInternal(NamingResourcesImpl.java:975)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5551)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:832)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.destroyInternal(ContainerBase.java:1012)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:832)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.destroyInternal(ContainerBase.java:1012)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:604)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
```

here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">
    <display-name>LabWebServletHibernate</display-name>

    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/xxx</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        <res-sharing-scope>Unshareable</res-sharing-scope>
    </resource-ref>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/beans.config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>model.misc.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
            <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

and beans.config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/xxx"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"></property>
        <!-- <property name="hibernateProperties"> <props> <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop> 
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop> <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop> 
            </props> </property> <property name="annotatedClasses"> <array> <value>model.CustomerBean</value> 
            <value>model.ProductBean</value> </array> </property> -->
    </bean>
    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
    <context:component-scan base-package="model"></context:component-scan>
</beans>
```

I'm good to share any other source if it's required, thanks for any help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Any of the jar dependencies of your project seems to be corrupted. You could try deleting all your local maven repo folder, or if you could manage to know which is the corrupted one, just delete it.

After one of theese actions, just update maven dependencies and it should start working

Comment: I have tried and still not word, and also same error:(

Comment: For a similar error (but not exactly the same), I could fix the problem by deleting the target folder of my project and rebuild it.

Answer (score 4):

This problem could be because the jar files that your project is using must have got corrupted. As my machine was windows, so I fix this error by going to following path

> C://Users/{user-name}/.m2/repository/

By deleting all the files and folders in this repository.
These jars will get downloaded again and after restarting and cleaning your workspace in eclipse this error was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem came out when I delete a dependency in pom.xml. Then I just update the maven dependency (right click the Project -> Maven -> Update Project) and clean my project(project -> clean) ,didn't work. 
**Finally, I just remove the project from the tomcat server, and then add the project again**. It work!

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Maven, don't create lib folder under WEB-INF instead please add dependency tag in pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

Not sure is this case with you also, but cleaning Apache server in eclipse completely worked for me. it occurred due to stopping server clean in middle of process. this resolved my error. try cleaning server

Answer (score 0):

Add following inur Pom file

```
</properties>
    <tomcat.version>8.0.30</tomcat.version>
</properties>
```